# C# ASP.net Login control with Master Page, Unable to intercept events

Tags: c#, asp.net, login-control

I am using C# ASP.Net to create a simple website.  I am using a master page (MasterPage.master).

I am trying to set up an asp:Login control, and intercept the LoginError event, so that I can change the FailureText to reflect the nature of the login failure.

On the Login.aspx.cs page, I have a fn that attempts to respond the LoginError event

`protected void Login1_LoginError(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Reset the Login1.FailureText string according to what has gone wrong
}`

This is not firing.

If I am using a master page, is the name of the control mangled?  I have tried using "ContentPlaceHolder1_Login1_LoginError" as the response function, and tons of other variants.

I have tried trapping other events such as Login1_Authenticate etc, but they are not working, so I assume I am not using the controls' correct name.  It should work and it's driving me nuts!

Thanks in advance for any help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't show how you defined your Login control in Login1.aspx so I am assuming you didn't set the OnLoginError event.

It should be:

```
<asp:Login ID="Login1" runat="server" OnLoginError="Login1_LoginError">
</asp:Login>
```

Comment: Yes, exactly right, I am mortified that I am such a klutz, but really really happy that you figured it out.  You have my immense gratitude!